# Confusion using C# parallel and sequential arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I'm taking an intro course and haven't had much trouble until we were introduced to methods and arrays. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to run a sequence search for an array that allows me to take a user input Zip Code, see if it is inside a Zip Code text file. 
If it is, I need to see what index subscript it is inside another text file "AGI Text File" and output the the AGI number to my agiOutputLabel.

If anyone can clear up my misunderstanding or explain parallel to me that makes better sense than my textbook I would appreciate it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace AGI_Florida
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {          
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        // Creating an array method
        private void SetZipArray(int[] zips)
        {

        }
        private void SetAGIArray(double[] agi)
        {

        }

        private void FindAGI(int[] zips, int agi)
        {
            bool found = false;
            int index = 0;
            int position = -1;

            while (!found && index < zips.Length)
            {
                if (zips[index] == agi)
                {
                    found = true;
                    position = index;
                }
                index++;
            }
            return;
        }



        private void getAgiButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Initializing the array with 917 spaces
                int[] zips = new int[917];
                int[] agi = new int[917];

                // Pulling array from text file
                StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("AGI_FL_ZipCodes-               1.txt");
                // Setting index to 0 so the loop knows to stop at 917 spaces
                int index = 0;
                // Running loop
                while ((index < zips.Length) && (!inputFile.EndOfStream))
                {
                    // Creating the index from the zip and parsing it 
                    zips[index] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                    index++;
                }
                inputFile.Close();

                int zipInput;


                if (int.TryParse(zipInputTextBox.Text, out zipInput))
                {
                    if (zipInput > 32003 && zipInput < 34997)
                    {
                        if (zipInput != -1)
                    {
                            MessageBox.Show(agi.ToString());

                    }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid zip code");
                    }

                }


                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid zip code");

                    zipInputTextBox.Text = " ";
                    zipInputTextBox.Focus();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        private void getAverageAgiButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // initialize new array
            double[] agi = new double[917];

            StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("AGI_FL-1-1.txt");
            // Setting index to 0 so the loop knows to stop at 917 spaces
            int index = 0;

            while ((index < agi.Length) && (!inputFile.EndOfStream))
            {
                // Creating the index from the zip and parsing it 
                agi[index] = double.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                index++;
            }
            inputFile.Close();

            // create a variable sum
            double sum = 0;

            // create a loop to read through the text file
            for (index = 0; index < agi.Length; index++)
            {
                // sum the index of values
                sum += agi[index];
            }

            // perform calculations
            double averageAgi = sum / (double) agi.Length;
            // print to label
            agiLabel.Text = averageAgi.ToString("c");

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your example have nothing to do with parallel. Please provide some specific problem you don't understand. Other way your question are too broad and unclear

Comment: The parallel was stated to search between two different text lines.  i.e.: 

Get user input zipcode
Check user input zipcode value is inside "zip code fl .txt"
if zipcode value is in "zipcode-fl.txt"
find subscript value
return subscript to FindAGI method
Print AGI to user

Answer (score -1):

First, welcome to coding!

There are lots of opportunities for improvement here. Lets make some of the code a bit cleaner

## Magic numbers.

Lets get rid of that magic number 917. Instead of creating an array of known length and then going to a file with unknow data in it and hoping they line up, why not just use the length of the data in the file

```
var filePath = "AGI_FL_ZipCodes-1.txt";
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath); //Nicer version of File.OpenText +ReadLine+EndOfStream+whileloop
int[] zips = new int[allLines.Length];  //instead of hard coded magic value of 917;
```

## Parsing and loops

However now you still have to read and parse all of the values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
{
    var line = allLines[i];
    zips[i] = int.Parse(line);  //Chance of an error here is the file is invalid :-/
}
```

## Conditional checks

You have a conditional check `if (zipInput > 32003 && zipInput < 34997)` which is fine. However considering our code is read more often than it is written, it is nice to format this in a way that is visually obvious what is happening. By moving the boundary values to the edge of the statement and having all the comparison operators pointing the same way, we can see that we want zipInput value *between* 32003 and 34997 (exclusive)

```
if (32003 < zipInput && zipInput < 34997)
```

## Dead code

Next you check if the `zipInput` is not equal to -1. This is unnecessary due to the check immediately before it. All values between 32003 and 34997 are not equal to -1.

You also declare the `agi` variable and never use it. You can delete this line

```
int[] agi = new int[917];
```

## Finding values in an array

Your `FindAGI` method look pretty good. However I would "upgrade" it to be a function that returns the value you are looking for.

```
private int IndexOf(int[] source, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if (source[i] == value)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that it will terminate as soon as it finds the element. If no match is made, then it will return -1 (which is pretty standard behaviour).

This may help you get on your way, but right now I dont see where any of this code is actually used i.e. the `FindAGI` (now `IndexOf`) doesn't appear to be referenced.

Comment: I think that maybe where I'm confused. I want the subscript from one text file to show me a position so I can reference it to the other text file. I think I'm unable to reference the method header to the body.

Comment: Sorry, but answer have nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: Sure, but can anyone figure out what the question actually is?